# Added Column via attribute table in QGIS will not show up in style menu

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, spatialite

I have my data within a spatialite DB. I added a line feature to the canvas in QGIS, opened up the attribute table and the field calculator and added a new column while calculating something. When I want to style this line feature layer, I can not choose the new column in the styling menu . Why is that?

Comment: Try using the 'change vector data source' plugin, right-click the layer, then click 'ok' to refresh the view of the data in the database...